# Turning functions to OOP

Tags: python, arrays, oop, recursion, initialization

I have a json dictonary like so:

```
{
  "name": "Root Folder",
  "type": "folder",
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "Folder A",
      "type": "folder",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "Folder A-A",
          "type": "folder",
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "File A-A-1",
              "type": "file",
              "children": []
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Folder A-B",
          "type": "folder",
          "children": []
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Folder B",
      "type": "folder",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "Folder B-A",
          "type": "folder",
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "Folder B-A-A",
              "type": "folder",
              "children": []
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Folder B-B",
          "type": "folder",
          "children": []
        }
     ]
   },
   {
      "name": "File Root",
      "type": "file",
      "children": []
   }
  ]
}
```

from this dictonary I want to automatically get the values "Path", "Name" and "type" for every member as well as the level, so root is level0, Folder A level 1, folder AA level 2 and so on.

For this goal I created the following Python code which takes a json-dictionary and puts the values from it in arrays:

```
import json
import os
from jinja2 import Template


with open('Folder_structure.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

def arr4tmpl(data,arr_path,arr_name,arr_type,arr_level):

    for child in data['children']:

        arr_path.extend([child['path']])
        arr_name.extend([child['name']])
        arr_type.extend([child['type']])
        arr_level.extend([arr4tmpl.level])

        arr4tmpl.level+=1
        arr4tmpl(child,arr_path,arr_name,arr_type,arr_level)
        arr4tmpl.level-=1

    return(arr_path,arr_name,arr_type,arr_level)

def main():
    arr4tmpl.level = 0
    arr=[]
    arr_path=[]
    arr_name=[]
    arr_type=[]
    arr_level=[]

(arr_path,arr_name,arr_type,arr_level)=arr4tmpl(data,arr_path,arr_name,arr_type,arr_level)
```

This works just fine, but now it has to be turned into an object oriented solution. So I thought of the following *(edited according to answers, thanks for that)*:

```
import json
import os
from jinja2 import Template

class CreateTemplate(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.arr_path=[]
        self.arr_name=[]
        self.arr_type=[]
        self.arr_level=[]
        self.level=0


    def arr4tmpl(self,data,level):
        for child in data['children']:

            arr_path.extend([child['path']])
            arr_name.extend([child['name']])
            arr_type.extend([child['type']])
            arr_level.extend([level])

            level+=1
            arr4tmpl(self,child,level)
            level-=1


        return(arr_path,arr_name,arr_type,arr_level)


with open('Folder_structure.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
template=CreateTemplate()
template.arr4tmpl(data,level)
```

The idea is to initialize the parameters over **init** Method and then extend them in the arr4tmpl method. 
To my understanding, creating the object should execute the init Method, but when executing the code I get Error:

```
File "Folder_structure.py", line 34, in <module>
template.arr4tmpl(data,level)
NameError: name 'level' is not defined
```

Comment: you aren't calling the members of the class

Comment: Don't forget that you still need to reference `self` inside your `arr4tmpl` method -- so `arr_path.extend(...)` should likely be `self.arr_path.extend(...)`, etc.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.  
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.
"Doesn't work" is not a problem specification.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to modify object variables, you have to refer to them using self

```
def arr4tmpl(self,data,level):
    for child in data['children']:    

        self.arr_path.extend([child['path']])
        self.arr_name.extend([child['name']]) 
        self.arr_type.extend([child['type']])
        self.arr_level.extend([level])

        self.level+=1
        self.arr4tmpl(self,child,level) #BUT this line will cause all sorts of recursion issues, since you don't have a stop criteria
        self.level-=1


    return(arr_path,arr_name,arr_type,arr_level)
```

Answer (score 0):

ah yes, I actually found a way:

```
import json
import os
from jinja2 import Template

class CreateTemplate(object):

    arr_path=[]
    arr_name=[]
    arr_type=[]
    arr_level=[]
    level=0



    def arr4tmpl(self,data):
        for child in data['children']:

            self.arr_path.extend([child['path']])
            self.arr_name.extend([child['name']])
            self.arr_type.extend([child['type']])
            self.arr_level.extend([self.level])

            self.level+=1
            self.arr4tmpl(child)
            self.level-=1


        return(self.arr_path,self.arr_name,self.arr_type,self.arr_level)


with open('Folder_structure.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
template=CreateTemplate()

template.arr4tmpl(data)
```

not sure why init doesn't also work because I figured it would initialize the parameters when the object is created and then these variables could be used for the method arr4tmpl.

Also not sure if the arr4tmpl method could be improved, but at least it does create those arrays now. Thanks!